What does it mean for a chord to be relative to the Dominant?
From Max Reger's Modulation:

"...relative (E minor) to the Dominant (G major) of C major [...] this E minor (1st inversion) which is also relative to the subdominant (G major) of D Major..."
When he says relative does he mean very similar as in Em differs from Gmaj only in the E, and is it important for it to be in 1st inversion?

That's really bad writing.

Rather, it is a bad translation.

Other answers here have already explained well that this is supposed to mean the relative minor chord to the the dominant chord. This is a translation of the original German text:

Note that in German the relative minor/major is called the parallel minor/major or simply the parallel (makes more sense in German). I suppose the translation remained too idiomatic to the German text.
A better translation of the text would rather be something like:

Tonic C-major; relative minor (E-minor) of the dominant (G-major) of C-major; this E-minor is reinterpreted (first inversion) as the relative minor of the Subdominant (G-major) of D-major. (Cadence!)

But essentially this says the modulation is

Tonic of C major; Dominant of C-major; Reinterpretation of said dominant as subdominant of D-major; Cadence.

It is just that this dominant in the bass is not reflected in the melody, which has E instead of D, technically turning this technically into first inversion of e-minor, or a substituted 6th, which is a common substitution, especially on the subdominant. Reger simply wants to point out the fact that this chord serves as dominant of C-major and as subdominant of D-major, while also pointing out that it is technically substituted by the first inversion of the relative minor of the chord.
Note that this important, as this e-minor could also be simply interpreted as third scale degree as preparation of the subdominant (which would thus go C - Em - F - G - C, a variant of C - C6 - F - G - C).

How confusing that English "relative" is German "parallel." What does German use for English "parallel"?

@phoog Variante.

C>Em I see, but F>G>C?

@Tim I - III - IV - V - I cadence, typical for viennese classical period (e.g. Joseph Haydn). Though typically as I - I6 - ....

Except the OP's cadence is also a key change/modulation. And should III be iii?

@Tim Yes, and this modulation somewhat requires a specific (but not esoteric) interpretation of that chord. Also scale degree notation is not exactly universal, so I suppose for you III is major and iii is minor. For me it isn’t. For me III is the triad naturally formed on the third scale degree, while the major one would require an alteration III♯. If you look at the excerpt of the OP and the original text you’ll see just uppercase use.

Respective to its function in the modulation, the V 6-4 chord (A F# D) is articulated in this way solely to provide smoother voice leading?

"Relative" is used here to describe the minor chord that is a minor third below a major chord; this sense is more commonly used to describe the same relationship between keys.
In other words, E minor is the relative minor of G major, and G major is both the dominant of C major and the subdominant of D major.  Thus, in the symbols shown at the bottom of the image, the relative minor, which is E minor, is analyzed both as the third degree of C major and the second degree of D major.

G major is the dominant key of C major.  E minor is the 'relative minor' of G major.  Relative keys are, indeed, 'very similar'.  E minor and G major have the same key signature and use the same set of notes (in the 'natural minor' form of the scale at least).  They are very similar.  But 'relative' has a rather more precise musical meaning.
No, being in first inversion is immaterial.
As a stand-alone statement the writing you showed us is almost impenetrable.   It might make more sense as part of a whole chapter discussing chord and key relationships.

In layman's terms, that sequence is C, G (or Em), D, A, D.
Maybe that makes more sense to us mere mortals!
Working backwards, the last D is modulated to using the dominant of G - D.
The G (/Em) is the dominant of the tonic at that time - C. Using the 1st inversion gives us more of a dominant feeling - in fact, it could be argued that it is in fact G rather than Em.
Then the D>A>D is new tonic >new dominant > new tonic. (D>A>D) Thus a modulation from key C to key D.
The relative bit is not too clear, and can only refer to Em being the relative minor of G - or G is the relative major of Em. So, if indeed, the chord is Em, then that's the relative minor of the dominant of the chord of C major. Quite convoluted...
